# how to group multiple elements (like fieldset in html) using jaspersoft

Tags: jasper-reports

[image]How to group multiple elements using jaspersoft studio. I tried using frames but it accommodates a single element. I just want like fieldset and legend in html. any idea ??

Comment: You can use frames, they group multiple elements. Could you elaborate more on your problem that you are facing?

Comment: @KahiniWadhawan check my image uploaded. i have numerous field-sets like this and a grid in my report. how to achieve such report??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of sub-report, it provides great flexibility.

Thanks